# How to get multiple days events on table_calendar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How can I set my table_calendar parameters to get events displayed as the image shown below :
[image]

Precisely the periods from 10 to 13.

If table_calendar is not able to do this, can someone point me to the right Widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it.

From table_calendar you have to add builders for `CalendarBuilders`.

```
 builders: CalendarBuilders(
     markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
         if (events.isNotEmpty) {
             children.add(
                 Positioned(
                     right: 1,
                     top: 1,
                     child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
                 ),
             );
         }
     }
 );
```

For this builders set a childer for events dates array.

And in yout `_buildEventsMarker`

```
Widget _buildEventsMarker() {
   return Container(
      width: 80.0,
      height: 20.0,

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.blue,
         shape:  BoxShape.rectangle ,
         borderRadius: null,
      ),
    );
}
```

You can add Text inside `Container` to display event name (don't handle it for now)

Comment: I would be more than happy if you can elaborate what the children is in the above code? Do you have any working sample that you can share ? I was looking for the exact implementation of multi days events in table_calendar?